# Iterate within the payload in mule

Tags: db2, mule, iteration, payload

I am retrieving some rows from the database. For example, after retrieving I have two rows as the payload. I would like to iterate within the rows. The retrieved two rows are as follows,

```
[{PAYLOAD_MSG=PU, SENSITIVEDATAINDICATOR=Y, ERRORMESSAGE=User generated exception test, 
INTERFACEID=I0826, EXCEPTIONID=73, PAYLOADMSGID=I0826MessTesting0002, SEVERITY=2, INTERFACENAME=replay, 
SOURCEPROTOCOL=MQ, CREATIONTIME=2016-03-01 08:29:36.211319, EVENTSOURCE=MQ_Input.transaction.Rollback}, 
{PAYLOAD_MSG=UvdjI, SENSITIVEDATAINDICATOR=N, ERRORMESSAGE=User generated exception test, INTERFACEID=I0826,
EXCEPTIONID=72, PAYLOADMSGID=I0826MessTesting0001, SEVERITY=2, INTERFACENAME=replay, SOURCEPROTOCOL=MQ, 
CREATIONTIME=2016-03-01 08:29:36.211319, EVENTSOURCE=MQ_Input.transaction.Rollback}]
```

I want to access the Payload_Msg of the first row and as well as the second row. Specifically how can this be done?  I have tried the following ways,

## [payload[0].Payload_Msg], #[payload.Payload_Msg]. But they were not working. Could someone help to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForEach loop to iterate and access objects.

```
  <foreach collection="payload">
             <logger message="#[payload.PAYLOAD_MSG]"/>
         </foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

**#[payload[0].PAYLOAD_MSG] must work else check with #[message.payload[0] PAYLOAD_MSG]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foreach component, but first set it to a flow var so you can still access it within the Foreach component. Another way to handle this is to use the Collection Splitter component.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *Collection Splitter* after the database connector to process each records one by one. Then you can use `#[payload.Payload_Msg]` in the Logger to retrieve the value.